# A question about the Skorokhod topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, skorohod-space

I have a question which may be naive but I can not find the answer in general reference about Skorokhod topology.

Let $\{w_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence of cadlag functions defined on $[0,1]$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(w_n,w_0)=0,$$

where $\rho$ denotes the Skorokhod distance. Then we know that there exists a countable set $T\subseteq [0,1]$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n(t)=w_0(t),~ \forall t\in [0,1]\backslash T$$

My question is if one has

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(w_n,v_n)=0$$

then one can also find a countable set $T\subseteq [0,1]$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(w_n(t)-v_n(t))=0,~ \forall t\in [0,1]\backslash T$$

Many thx for the reply!